Did the Balkan people emigrate in Greece during Classical Greece era?
Recent studies (Lazaridis et al. 2016, Lazaridis et al. 2022) show that the Indo-Europeans of the Yamnaya culture already had migrate in the Balkans and Greece in the 3000-1000 BCE and 1500-1000 BCE, so as to leave traces in the DNA of the people of the regions in those time (although more in the Balkans than in Greece).
Did the Balkan people emigrate to the centre and south of Greece (e.g. Athens) before and during the Classical Greece Era (5th and 4th centuries)?
The picture below from (Lazidis et al. 2022) shows the migration movements mentioned in the question, and what is meant by "Balkan people", "Greece", etc.

It would make all sense, since those areas where the most developed.
Also, some Classical Greece philosophers (e.g. Aristotle) resemble, according to contemporary busts, very much today's Greeks, whom, according to studies, share most of their DNA with 2,000 BCE Aegeans from Northern Greece (Clemente et al. 2021).
References:
Clemente, F., Unterländer, M., Dolgova, O., Amorim, C. E. G., Coroado-Santos, F., Neuenschwander, S., ... & Papageorgopoulou, C. (2021). The genomic history of the Aegean palatial civilizations. Cell, 184(10), 2565-2586.
Lazaridis, I., Nadel, D., Rollefson, G., Merrett, D. C., Rohland, N., Mallick, S., ... & Reich, D. (2016). Genomic insights into the origin of farming in the ancient Near East. Nature, 536(7617), 419-424.
Lazaridis, I., Alpaslan-Roodenberg, S., Acar, A., Açıkkol, A., Agelarakis, A., Aghikyan, L., ... & Ruka, R. (2022). The genetic history of the Southern Arc: A bridge between West Asia and Europe. Science, 377(6609), eabm4247.

Perhaps this is more fodder for an answer than an issue with the question, but you can't really mix linguistics ("Indo-Europeans") with genetics quite this freely. They can sometimes be correlated, particularly when sudden changes are seen. However, genes haven't historically been much of a respecter of cultural boundaries. The extreme example would be modern Americans, who are definitely a cohesive culture, but can have ancestors (even parents or grandparents) from anywhere on earth.

a couple of thing that - at least to me - just don't add up:

why athens should not be greece? there is something in the source (that are not available to the reader of the question) about that?
the resemblance of the busts seems like cherry picking: I can find a lot of greek that doesn't resemble aristoteles (and the beard doesn't help)


@T.E.D. Language and genetics can be separated, and so for instance in the Bronze Age the Indo-Europeans arrived in Greece but nonetheless they did not immersed the region genetically, only the language spread the territory (in contrast, in Italy, they was a massive genetical shift when they arrived in the peninsula in 2000 BC). "modern Americans" if I am not mistaken, Americans differentiate between Afro-Americans, ABC, Caucasian Americans, etc. Patriotism around the flag and the constitution nonetheless unites the American people.

@Starckman given that I don't see any update of the question, my objection is: if balkan people migrated in greece, and athens is in greece, isn't the answer is in your own question ? (that is, yes they do)
the similarity of one person among 11 millions, is not a proof, so I can not say that if a greek is similar to me, then I'm greek

@DanM I corrected my question.

The main ethnic group who emigrated to the Greek mainland-(primarily the Central and Southern Hellenic mainland) between 1100-800 BC/BCE-(a few centuries before the "Classical era" of Greece), were the Dorians.
Exactly where the Dorians came from is not entirely known....it is likely that the Dorians existed North of present-day mainland Greece and according to very limited archeological evidence-(and I believe Herodotus as well), the Dorians probably originated in the Southern Balkans....more specifically, in the Albanian-Montenegro region-(i.e. the Ionian & Adriatic sea region).  As to whether or not the Ancient Dorians were ethno-racially related to the Illyrians-(the ancient Albanians), has also not been entirely proven-(Albanians tend to have a more distant Celtic kinship, whereas there is no verifiable evidence proving any Celtic kinship amongst the Ancient Greeks and in particular, the Ancient Dorians).
There were also the Ancient Aeolians who were reported to have originated to the North of Greece proper-(i.e. the Southern Balkan region), as well as the Ionians, whose ancient origins most likely were rooted in the Middle East.  However, for much of Greece's early demographic history, the Dorians, were the more dominant "Balkan" group who essentially transformed the demography and culture of Central and in particular, Southern Greece.  Prior to the arrival of the Dorians, much of the Hellenic mainland-(especially, the Peloponnesian region), was under Mycenaean control.
(Note:  A historical footnote.....The word, "Balkan" does not come into existence until The Ottoman Empire.  Etymologically speaking, the word, "Balkans", was a Turkish nickname given to the peoples of Southeast Europe who lived in the "mountainous" region of the empire-(i.e. Central and Northern Greece, Bulgaria, Albania, much of the former Yugoslavia and Romania).

Thank you very much. Wikipedia on Dorian invasion "The Dorian invasion is a concept devised by historians of Ancient Greece to explain the replacement of pre-classical dialects and traditions in Southern Greece by the ones that prevailed in Classical Greece." It's astonishing that, IMK, there is no DNA study of the Classical Greece, especially albeit this phenomenon of the Dorian invasion... I mean, I saw a lot of DNA studies on the Neolithic, the Bronze Age, etc. but not the period not that far ago which is the cradle of modern science and philosophy...

Thank you for the comment.  I should mention that there was, in recent years, a dental study of Ancient Cretan teeth remains from the Minoan period-(3600 plus years ago) that attempted to match the dental structures of many contemporary Cretan residents....it turned our that the match was almost 100%! that is to say, the Greco-Cretan peoples-(at least dentally), actually share a distant biological heritage with their Minoan forebearers-(at least a partial biological heritage).

The problem, though, with DNA testing and Classical Greece, is that there is, to the best of my knowledge, few ancient skeletal remains which are available for DNA testing and examination.  There are Ancient burial sites throughout Greece-(especially in Athens), though the skeletal remains of the Ancient Greeks, are hard to detect....except, perhaps, through more improved archeological methods which may lead to the literal unearthing of classical Greek skeletal remains, which will be necessary for any verifiable DNA testing.  (Aristotle's tomb was recently unearthed in his Macedonian.....

home town of Stagira, King Philip's tomb/ossuary is located in the Macedonian archeological site of Vergina/Aegea and Homer is reported to be entombed on the Cycladic island of Ios.  Archimedes was entombed at a cave in Syracuse, Sicily, though today, it is a cenotaph.  There are a handful of Ancient Greek heavyweights who are identifiably entombed, though again....just a handful).

So the Greeks of the Archaic, Classical and Hellenistic periods were in fact... Dorians, aka Balkans? I ask that because Wiki says "The Dorian invasion is a concept devised by historians of Ancient Greece to explain the replacement of pre-classical dialects and traditions in Southern Greece by the ones that prevailed in Classical Greece." It doesn't sound like the Roman invasion in France or the Arab invasion in the Middle East/North Africa/Spain, or the Franks invasion in France where the rulers ruled an ethnolinguistically different population

From your answer and the Wiki, it sounds as if the previous population vanished in some way, to the benefits of the newcomers, i.e. the Dorians. Is it the direction that the current evidence point to?

Well, I am not sure if the Myceneans vanished....most likely they were forcibly assimilated into the Dorian population...(a type of Dorianization).  We know that the Myceneans were the earliest Greek speaking peoples, though the question is as to whether or not the Northern Dorians were also an early Greek speaking peoples.  The Dorians probably spoke a more primitive form of Greek-(when compared with the more sophisticated Myceneans), though we are still not entirely sure if they were ethno-racially Hellenic-(it's likely they were, but we still do not have enough verifiable evidence).

It is the "and traditions" that attracted my attention. If the Dorians were simply rulers, they would change the political structure, maybe the language, but if even the traditions were modified, then, in my impression, it points to a significant demographic replacement. Indeed, traditions are, IMU, very fine-grained social habits that can hardly be adopted by a different ethnic populations.

Given that the Dorians spoke Greek (in fact the Greek that is ancestral to modern Greek) it really isn't that much of a mystery where they came from. It had to be somewhere in the Greek-speaking world, which narrows it down geographically quite a bit.
